# Irreducible polynomial modulo 2

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I need to prove that polynomial $f(x) = x^{10}+x^{3}+1$ is irreducible modulo $2$.
It is irreducible if $f|x^{1024}-x$, isn't it? I can use polynomial long division to check it, but this is not elegant. Is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to go to the polynomial $x^{2^{10}}-x$ which, by the way, equals
$$x^{2^{10}}-x = \prod_{f \textrm{ irred} \deg | 10} f $$
(so that would work only in the opposite direction in fact),
rather, show that it does not have any factor of degree $5$, $4$, $3$, $2$, $1$,
that is, show that the gcd of this polynomial with each of the polynomials
$$ x^{2^5}-x,\  x^{2^4}-x,\  x^{2^3} - x$$
is $1$, which is not too hard.